# Cron - failing calling external script (Environment Variables initialization)

Tags: cron, pexpect

A script which partial goal is to periodically connect to a range of hosts and rsync some logs back to a central server works flawlessly when manually calling it,

```
python ./apex2zabbix.py --sync="Client_Service_Platform Emtity"
```

however, when called through cron, dies with an .EOF on the remote rsync step,

```
command = "/usr/bin/rsync -e ssh -a %s --compress=9 -pgtov %s %s --exclude='*' %s@%s:%s%s %s" % (remote_rsync_binary, excluded_expression, filters_expression, user, ip, source_path, file_filter, target_path)

p = pexpect.spawn(command, timeout=360)

i = p.expect([ssh_new_conn,'[pP]assword:',pexpect.EOF])
print 'Initial pexpect command output: ', i
if i == 0:
    # send 'yes'
    p.sendline('yes')
    i = p.expect(['[pP]assword:',pexpect.EOF])
    if i == 0:
        # send the password
        p.sendline(passwd)
        p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
elif i == 1:
    # send the password
    p.sendline(passwd)
    p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
elif i == 2:
    print "key or connection timeout"
    pass
```

returning

```
Initial pexpect command output: 2
```

What may be causing it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sigh...
Hadn't I had a brain stop, I would have remembered to add

```
print 'output:', p.before
```

and noticed it was returning

```
output: rsync: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)
```

contrary to my belief, the ssh in rsync -e is not an option, but a binary,
thus I should either add

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

to cron or specify the full path form, **/usr/bin/rsync -e /usr/bin/ssh**

```
command = "/usr/bin/rsync -e /usr/bin/ssh -a %s --compress=9 -pgtov %s %s --exclude='*' %s@%s:%s%s %s" % (remote_rsync_binary, excluded_expression, filters_expression, user, ip, source_path, file_filter, target_path)
```